# Mouseup to cancel all event under Mousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement a `div` resize code using `Jquery`. See [here](http://veershubhranshu.com/demo2.html).

For now it moves as per the mouse movement. The codes are here:

```
$('#top-left').mousedown(function(){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(document).mousemove(function(event){
        var current_width=$(".active").width();
        var current_height=$(".active").height();
        var position = $(".active").position();

        var new_width=current_width+(position.left-event.pageX);

        temp=$("#mouse").html();
        $("#mouse").html(temp+"<br />new_width= "+new_width);

        $(".active").css({top:event.pageY+"px"});
        //$(".active").css({width:new_width+"px"}); 
    });
});
$('#top-left').mouseup(function(){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

I want when `mouseup` is called, the events registered with current `div.active` gets removed. Please let me know if I am not clear.

Check the [JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3N6jP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `div.active` to have no events bound to it, just do:
    $('div.active').unbind()

For reference: [unbind() api reference](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/#unbind)

Additionally, since you are dealing with elements being added to the DOM, using .click() will not work, when dealing with dynamic elements, us on() as referenced [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

However, because the elements are dynamic, you need to use the 'delegate' feature of the on() method:

```
$( "parentElement" ).on( "click", "clickedElement", function() {
    alert( $( this ).text() );
    console.log(this); // will reference "clickedClicked", not "parentElement"
});
```

In short, delgation works by listening for events that bubble from a child element to it's non-dynamic parent. So, since dynamic children's events will bubble up, the parent element will always receive clicks from it's children elements.

Comment: New event listeners are not being created using this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3N6jP/6/ - I updated the fiddle. It's a lot closer now. I think you can get it from here. Let me know if you have any more questions, you can IM me MBulldogBooth

Comment: And I wasn't saying you were creating new listeners. I was saying when you remove() and prepend() elements, they don't get the original event listeners added to them. Unless you use the on() method and event delegation as I mentioned in the answer and put in the jsFiddle. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: When I am clicking another `div` then it is again associated with the same event. The `mouseup` for the previous `#top-left` is not being removed.